# Google webp library for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, webp

Is Google webp library available for iPhone/XCode ?
Is there a FAQ to compile this library from sources ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Check out [this tutorial](http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/1483/using-webp-to-reduce-native-ios-app-size/) for a nice implementation. The same person has posted this [sample code](https://github.com/carsonmcdonald/WebP-iOS-example) for using WebP with iOS.

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works perfectly... Is there a sample code as well for encoding an image ?

Answer (score 1):

You could also download the latest WebP iOS app:
http://code.google.com/p/webp/downloads/detail?name=webpiosapp-0.2.0.tar.gz&can=2&q=